# How do I post an image into a question

Tags: discussion

I have a question on the site about a connector, how do I put a photo or image of the connector into my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the upper left part of the window/frame where you write your question/answer you see small icon. Click on that icon and drag and drop in the window your picture. There is also link you can put URL of your picture from internet.
[image]